# Measuring concentration

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique

I am trying to measure the concentration of a Volatile Organic Compound (VOC) inside a liquid using Gas Chromatography (GC). The liquid contains particles that cannot be sent to a GC, so I am using the head-space method (allowing the organic compound to evaporate into the gas above the liquid--- see this link:http://www.chem.agilent.com/Library/applications/5990-3285EN.pdf)--

I let the contents of the liquid equilibrate with the air in the vial at 50 C-- and then I use the air as feed for the GC. However, the concentration in the air is rather small ~ 10-20 ppm. Is there a technique that can be used to increase the concentration of the VOC's?

I have wanted to use a smaller vial to collect my liquid, but the liquid splashes about and contaminates the cap of the vial, which makes me scared to inject a needle into it as I may wreck the needle.

**Update**

I tried to repeat the experiment with the vial at a higher temperature ~70 C. This lead to the needle clogging. I am unsure of the cause of the needle clogging but I suspect it may have something to do with water evaporating and taking some of the polymer particles with it. Once in the needle, the particles could get dry and solidify.

Comment: Explaining your intended technique a little more clearly might bring in more people with the ability to answer.

Comment: @dmckee, could you tell me where I should expand?

Comment: I had to deduce what you meant by *"the head-space method"*. Admittedly that wasn't hard after I stopped boggling and started thinking, but it never hurts to make things easy for the guy who might help you.

Comment: BTW--If the [Experimental or Applied Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/720/520) proposal is to go ahead, I think this is the kind of question that would be better there than here. (Of course, I don't see any problem with one site that includes this question.)

Comment: Which kind of "particles" make direct injection impossible? Is there some solvent? If yes, is it more volatile than that VOC?

Comment: It's a polymer. It's non-volatile.

Comment: A liquid polymer? Is it soluble in some solvent? Does the polymer  crack easily? GC people in our company use to inject polymer-containing samples dozens of times a day. (laquers etc)

Comment: Its a type of suspension of polymer in an aqueous liquid. It solidifies when the aqueous liquid evaporates.

Comment: AfaIk there a short "precolumns" (which can be easily disposed off) used in such cases. All this head space is not easy as long as You do not know the volatility/temperature of that VOC. Next is that You have to have all that equipment on the same temperature (higher than sample temp) to avoid condensation.

Comment: @Georg, perhaps you can help with this, I think I have identified the source of the issue. Part of the septum(in the GC instrument) is getting stuck in my needle. I have tried using both the gas needles (hole at the side) or liquid needles(hole at the bottom) and I am still facing the issue.

Comment: What is a VOC? What is a GC?

Comment: Could you please be specific about the liquid and the VOC? Can you use another solvent, besides air and "liquid"?

Comment: Can you use distillation to separate the liquid from the solid?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a technique that can be used to increase the concentration of the VOC's?

Presumably heating the container (gently!) will work. In the past I have found that a heat lamp is safe when one needs to heat a small quantity of liquid without allowing it to boil. You will--of course--need patience.

> I have wanted to use a smaller vial to collect my liquid, but the liquid splashes about and contaminates the cap of the vial, which makes me scared to inject a needle into it as I may wreck the needle.

'Fraid I can't help you there.

Comment: Patience and time I have. I just wish the concentration could be higher. I will try it again tomorrow at a slightly higher temperature, hopefully it will be better.